# How Can I Have Multiple Editor Part Collections?

Tags: 2010, web-part, development, custom-web-part-property

I have created a web part in SharePoint 2007 which has over 40 controls and I was able to make two different Tool Part classes to hold the different sections of the custom controls.  I am converting the part over to SharePoint 2010, and I am having a hard time getting two EditorPartCollection class to work on the same page.  How can I have two of these?  I am sure it is possible, I am just having a hard time getting this to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public override EditorPartCollection CreateEditorParts()
    {
        var editor = new ClockEditor
        {
            ID = ID + "_Editor",
            Title = "Custom Clock Editor"
        };
        return new EditorPartCollection(new EditorPart[] { editor });
    }


    public override EditorPartCollection CreateEditorParts()
    {
        var zoneEditor = new ZoneEditor
        {
            ID = ID + "_Editor",
            Title = "Time Zone Editor"
        };
        return new EditorPartCollection(new EditorPart[] { zoneEditor });
    }
```

Comment: Try EditorPartCollection(ICollection editorParts);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
public override EditorPartCollection CreateEditorParts()
{
    var zoneEditor = new ZoneEditor
    {
        ID = ID + "_Editor",
        Title = "Time Zone Editor"
    };
    var editor = new ClockEditor
    {
        ID = ID + "_Editor",
        Title = "Custom Clock Editor"
    };
    return new EditorPartCollection(new EditorPart[] { editor, zoneEditor });
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not seem to work right.  i do not think I did the return new EditorPartCollection(new EditorPart[] { editor, zoneEditor });
part right I am going to try again thanks.    I have for now just loaded all of the controls into the one editor part.  I really do not want to do this because I have so many controls.  It has been much neater to keep them separate.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That is it.  Thanks.  I was trying to return two instances of the EditorPartCollection and that is why it was not working.  Thank you.  I knew there had to be a way I was overlooking.  +1